# vb script to populate cell with data until it sees a populated cell and then continues with that

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Good Afternoon,

I am trying to create a VBscript that I can add in to excel that will hunt a column for data and then copy that data to each row below it until it sees a cell that is populated do the same with that.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you don't like "Yes" for an answer, you should disclose your problem: Do you need an algorithm for your task? Can't you implement your plan? Does your experimental script fail/break down (in that case: publish it)?

Comment: Hi Ekkehard,

I have so far created the first and last part of my script and I am stuck on the above problem. Guidance or an Algorithm would be ideal.

Comment: Part 1 will hunt through a column and delete the rows for selected text that you define through an action box (Already Produced.
Part 2 is where I need an algorithm to hunt through a column and copy a cell that has data to the below cells until it hits a cell with data already and then does the same with that until the end of the data. this is where I am struggling because I am not to sure where to start.
Part 3 creates a pivot table from the data into a separate worksheet. (Already produced)
Let me know if you need anymore information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algorithm to fill empties in a collection (array, column, range) with the preceding non-empty value

1. init (default) value v
2. for each element in collection
3. if e is empty, replace e with v, else update v with non-empty e

demo code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim a ' array to fill
For Each a In Array(Split("1  47 5 "), Split("  3  5 0"))
    WScript.Echo 0, Join(a, "*")
    Dim v : v = "0" ' value to fill empties
    Dim i
    For i = 0 To UBound(a)
        If "" = a(i) Then ' found empty, fill with v
           a(i) = v
        Else ' found non-empty, update v
           v = a(i)
        End If
    Next
    WScript.Echo 1, Join(a, "*")
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 24656643.vbs
0 1**47*5*
1 1*1*47*5*5
0 **3**5*0
1 0*0*3*3*5*0
```

Comment: Hi Ekkehard, I am just testing this

the data I am using is:

Emp No.
100001






100005




100009






100010





100012







100020






100021





Emp No.
100001






100005




100009






100010





100012







100020






100021





in column C for example